# Can't add 2nd plot to Log Transform figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Per below code, plotting the log transformation of  historical price data works fine, however when any  2nd plot (eg. closing price) is added to the figure, log transform is plotted as ts=0 ?!

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

df = pd.read_csv('historical_price_data.csv')
df = df[::-1]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, infer_datetime_format=True) 

# Set index to Date returns KeyError: "['Date'] not in index"
# df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# Log Transform 
log_transform = df['Close']
df['log'] = np.log(log_transform)

# Log transform plots fine by itself
ax = df[['Date', 'log']].plot(figsize=(14, 7), x='Date')

# Adding another plot to the figure results in log_transform being set to 0 !
ax = df[['Date', 'Close']].plot(figsize=(14, 7), x='Date', ax=ax)

plot.show()
```

[image: Log Transformation plots by itself]

[image: Adding 2nd plot breaks Log Transformation plot]

Just to note that plotting them with a single loc instead of 2 results in the same problem with the log transform line getting squashed to 0:

```
ax = df[['Date', 'log', 'Close']].plot(x='Date')
```

Comment: You may want to plot on a second y axis - `ax2=ax.twinx()`

Comment: @DavidG how would df['log'] be added to ax2 so that they are both plotted in a single figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log-transformed data is orders of magnitude smaller (by definition almost) than the original data, so it's visually collapsed on the plot: `Close` peaks at about `20000`, while `log` peaks at about `10`.

It rarely makes sense to compare the original data to the log transform on the same plot.

If you ever fix your index issue, use the following to plot on separate plots:

```
df['log'] = np.log(df['Close'])
df[['Close', 'log']].plot(figsize=(14, 7), subplots=True)
```

Comment: I am baffled by the index issue. Could pandas already be setting the index to Date? I thought someone mentioned if that were the case and you tried adding it again, you might see such behavior.

Comment: @Compustretch try `df.columns = ['Date', 'Close']` right after `read_csv`. I can't reproduce your issue on my side, everything's running fine. Try restarting your environment and rerunning the code.

Comment: How is it working for you! I've tried on 2 different machines, OSX per previous, and a Linux box with pandas 0.23.3 & matplotlib: 2.2.2. -- SO won't let me post a follow up yet, but I would be interested in how you have it working? The code I'm running is very simple: https://pastebin.com/krXJ9YWW

Comment: @Compustretch `df.index` returns the index.

Comment: I'm still baffled how this is working for you. Are you able to use the same exact code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195269/key-error-date-not-in-index-only-when-adding-date-to-index

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to plot your data on the same subplot, rather than on 2 separate ones, you can create a secondary y axis using `ax.twinx()`. You can than pass this new axes as an argument to the plotting function using `ax=`:

```
ax = df[['Date', 'log']].plot(figsize=(14, 7), x='Date')

ax2 = ax.twinx() # create seconday y axis and pass it into the plotting function below
ax2 = df[['Date', 'Close']].plot(figsize=(14, 7), x='Date', ax=ax2)
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidG, and sorry I was so hasty in accepting Andrey's answer.

Comment: @Compustretch No problem, you may accept any answer you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another syntax:

```
df['rolling_mean'] = df.Close.rolling(window=7).mean()
df.plot(x='Date', y=['Close', 'rolling_mean'], logy=True, figsize=(15,5))
```

with a simulated dataset:

[image]