# Key error "Date not in index" only when adding Date to index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

This one is baffling given how simple the code is, and yet it's giving the same error on separate Linux and OSX boxes. If df.set_index('Date', inplace=True) is run, then plot(x='Date') returns KeyError: "['Date'] not in index" -- But if df.set_index() is commented out, the error goes away.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

df = pd.read_csv('historical_price_data.csv')

# Seemingly makes no difference either way. 
df.columns = ['Date', 'Close']

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, infer_datetime_format=True) 

# Uncommenting this line results in error (below) when plot(x='Date') is called. 
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Seemingly makes no difference. 
# df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# If set_index('Date') above, then plot(x='Date') returns KeyError: "['Date'] not in index"
df[['Date', 'Close']].plot(x='Date')

plot.show()
```

This is the data set I'm using:

```
Date,Close
2018-08-29,7059.7
2018-08-28,7071.01
2018-08-27,6911.9
2018-08-26,6709.98
2018-08-25,6737.52
2018-08-24,6690.88
2018-08-23,6526.36
2018-08-22,6359.99
2018-08-21,6475.9
2018-08-20,6258.74
```

Comment: I  kinda need to index on my Date column and not just a range index. This question is not about how to trivially plot 10 rows, it's just a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: (Previous comment was in response to a comment that has since been deleted.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=False)
```

instead of:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: When you set date as index, by default it removes the date column from your dataframe, that's why you got the error saying Date not in index(index here refers to the columns). By using the drop=False parameter, it tells pandas to keep the date filed when setting date as index.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want a line plot of the years on the x axis and close on y axis.

Changing the last line to :

```
df.plot('Date')
```

should do the trick.

To make the plot look more appealing you can replace the line:

```
   df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

with:

```
   df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%M-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do plot

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, infer_datetime_format=True) 
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df['Close'].plot()# set the index as x-axis for itself
```

[image]